# Introduce rows from a file to another file every other row

Tags: r, bash, shell

I have a dataset of Samples that looks like this:

```
SampleName1
SampleName2
SampleName3
SampleName4
SampleName5
```

And another dataset with information from every Sample that looks like this:

```
0101010101010
0101010101010
0101010101010
0101010101010
0101010101010
```

I would like my new data looking like this:

```
SampleName1
0101010101010
SampleName2
0101010101010
SampleName3
0101010101010
SampleName4
0101010101010
SampleName5
0101010101010
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[++i]=$0;next} {print a[FNR] RS $0}' file1 file2
SampleName1
0101010101010
SampleName2
0101010101010
SampleName3
0101010101010
SampleName4
0101010101010
SampleName5
0101010101010
```

Comment: Perfect! Works great!

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
paste -d'\n' file1 file2
```

with your data:

```
kent$  paste -d'\n' f1 f2
SampleName1
0101010101010
SampleName2
0101010101010
SampleName3
0101010101010
SampleName4
0101010101010
SampleName5
0101010101010
```

Answer (score 1):

In R, you can try:

```
f1<-read.table(text="SampleName1
SampleName2
SampleName3
SampleName4
SampleName5",stringsAsFactors=F)

f2<-read.table(text="0101010101010
0101010101010
0101010101010
0101010101010
0101010101010",colClasses="character")

n <- seq_along(f1[,'V1'])
data.frame(f3=unlist(lapply(n, function(x)c(f1[x,'V1'],f2[x,'V1']))))
```

And here is the result:

```
              f3
1    SampleName1
2  0101010101010
3    SampleName2
4  0101010101010
5    SampleName3
6  0101010101010
7    SampleName4
8  0101010101010
9    SampleName5
10 0101010101010
```